# Jar command exlude hidden files in any folder

Tags: linux, web-applications, ubuntu

I am creating a war file using the jar command. It has many folders with lots of sub folders etc. I am working on Ubuntu Linux and when I create the war all hidden files are also included in the war file. This doubles the size of the end product.

How do I exclude all hidden files ?

```
/my/path_to/folder/myfile.jsp
/my/path_to/folder/myfile.jsp~
/my/path_to/folder/myfile2.jsp
/my/path_to/folder/myfile2.jsp~
```

So I want to exclude any file ending in a ~

Thanks

Spunog

Answer (score 2):

If you want to eliminate results from a selection you can use the ^ (not) to do so.  This will exclude all files with a ~

```
jar cf myFile.war *[^~]
```

Added image for verification

[image]

Comment: My original line in the script is jar -cvf myapp.war *     Changing it to jar -cvf myapp.war *.[^~] Gives the following error       *.[^~] : no such file or directory

Comment: My applogies.  Try without the dot

Comment: Thanks for your help but that has no effect :( There are many subfolders all containing the hidden files. These remain. Perhaps I could delete the hidden files via my script before creating the jar

Comment: find . -type f -name "*~" -exec rm -f {} \;

Comment: Works on my machine as well.  I would post a new answer and approve

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org) for creating jar/war files because it is portable, so you will not need to rely on shell features for regex-based excluding files.

The simplest `ant` build.xml for your needs would be:

```
<project>
  <property name="classes.dir" value="." />
  <jar destfile="a.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}" excludes="**/*~" />
</project>
```

Comment: In fact you don't even need the `excludes` there because file names ending with a tilde are [excluded by default](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#defaultexcludes).

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -name "*~" -exec rm -f {} \;
```